# How can I insert java Strings into Database table?

Tags: javascript, java, html, sqlite, jsp

I have a database that I manage through a jsp file. I want to add some data to it, but I need the data to be taken from a String variable.
I tried the following code but the "VALUES" parameter doesn't accept variables. Any help?

```
function UploadNot() {
     <%
          String NotificationToUpload = "Test Notification";
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:d:\\Databases\\DataBase1.db");
          stat = conn.createStatement();
          String sql = "INSERT INTO Nots (Notifications) " +
               "VALUES (NotificationToUpload);";  //ERROR here, Does not accept variables, only direct Strings
          stat.executeUpdate(sql);
     %>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the "+" operator in order to concatenate your value.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Nots (Notifications) VALUES ('" +NotificationToUpload+ "');";
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get a syntax error: "javax.servlet.ServletException: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Notification": syntax error)"

Comment: You have to quote the value if it's not an integer field.

Comment: I edited your correction, you added incorrect whitespaces.